# Bind an ObservableCollection<string> to another ObservableCollection<MyType>

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I need to bind one ObservableCollection (**of type string**) to another ObservableCollection (**of type MyType**).  Both are DependencyProperties.

MyType has a string property to contain the string from the string collection, but also has other properties.

I want any changes made on the string collection to be reflected to the MyType collection, but how can i define this string-to-MyType conversion in the binding?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind ObservableCollections to each other. Only DependencyObjects support binding. You'd have to have a method to sync them up. Subscribe to the string collection INCC event and update the MyType collection.

Comment: Oh sorry, i meant two DependencyProperties of type ObservableCollection. Is it possible?

Comment: @moonlander, nope... you need to write code to sync them up.

Comment: Ok, i thought i could bind them programmatically. I'll try doing it using the CollectionChanged event of the strings collection. thanks.